# permalink structuring not working

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

My site is **[this](http://trackschoolbus.com/)** . when i update my permalink structure to **Day and name,Month and name ,Numeric,Post name** the pages shows **404 not found error** but when i change it to **Default:http://trackschoolbus.com/?p=123** it is working fine.no idea what is happening.I recently updated my **WordPress to 4.0** . got the issue after update.please help ,thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    you have not activated mod_rewrite and permitted it for your WordPress directory. 
    Make sure that Apache module is loaded and that you have AllowOverride All is in your  <Directory> section.

    HTAccess file

    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /wp/project/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /wp/project/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Comment: thanks for the reply .. how can i make that into action